# zoneSchedule not work correctly when the date is very far away

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

I receive notifications before the date I set when the date is scheduled for several months.

Anyone knows who to solve this isue ?

Here is My code :

```
scheduleNotification(
      DateTime date, String title, String description, int id) async {
    var tzDateNotif = tz.TZDateTime.from(date, tz.local);
    await _localNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      description,
      tzDateNotif,
      const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              'your channel id', 'your channel description')),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }
```

Comment: did you initialize the TZ with `tz.initializeTimeZones();
`

Comment: Yes I already did. And it works very well when I program it for a few minutes or a few hours, but for several months I get the notification after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **initializeTimeZones()** method from timezone package 
 in main method of your application if you want receive notifications in your current timezone

```dart
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  runApp(YourApp());
```

Comment: I have already initialized it, but the problem still occurs when I program it in several months.